# What is this Cable for? 4 Pin to 2 Pin from Riser to Perc in Dell R410

Tags: hardware, dell, perc6, dell-perc, dell-poweredge

I got a new raid card for a R410 server since the S300 that came with it doesn't support raid with Linux (No work around for this if SAS from what I could find).  The new card is the SAS H200.

Anyways, the RAID card has 2 pins on it and there is a cable that that connects to a 4 pin connection on the riser.  The cable only has two wires, one black and one red. On the board of the raid card to the pin connection says "j_sas_act".

What is this cable for?  My guess would be maybe LED status for the front panel or something like that, but I am just guessing....

To the left of the SAS connectors (1) there is the two pin Connector.  It is in the sketch below.

[alt text http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/Storlink/H200/en/UG/HTML/perc_h22.jpg](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/Storlink/H200/en/UG/HTML/perc_h22.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

j = jumper
sas = serial attached SCSI
act = action

This is an operation LED cable

Answer (score 1):

It's ***quite*** hard to answer if you don't tell the card's manufacturer and model and/or post a picture of it... my guess would be the same as yours, as with two pins you really can't do much more than lighting a LED; but it's just a guess.

---

### Update:

"j_sas_act" ***really*** looks like an activity LED. Howewer, it's not documented anywhere... this is all I was able to find: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/Storlink/H200/en/UG/PDF/H200.pdf

Comment: Sorry, card is the H200.